# Counting the number of mention depending on sentiment SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Apologies if this is a duplicate of anything, I wasn't finding answers which particularly did what I wanted.

I'm trying to write a SQL query which will return the count of rows which contain a positive, negative or neutral sentiment on one of the candidates in the dataset.

Here is a screenshot for reference

[image: List of column names, for reference the most important ones are candidate and sentiment]

Sentiment is one column but the values in it define the tweet to be positive, negative, or neutral. my goal is to have the query return something like this

[image: table depicting the candidate name and counts of how many times they were mentioned positively, negatively, and neutrally]

if anyone could give me an example on how to do this, I'd appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using specific COUNT() functions in your query like this.

```
SELECT name as `Candidate Name`, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sentiment='Negative' THEN 1 END) AS `Negative`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sentiment='Positive' THEN 1 END) AS `Positive`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sentiment='Neutral' THEN 1 END) AS `Neutral`,
    COUNT(*) AS `Total`

FROM [table]
    
GROUP BY candidate
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! this works great, it'll help me with the rest of the queries I have to do as well. One issue I has was with the from, though I was able to fix it simply by noticing it was missing. May want to add that for anyone who needs this in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I like using IF()'s or CASE WHEN's to solve this type of thing. Pivots are sometimes time consuming to think through.

```
SELECT
  Name as CandidateName,
  SUM(IF(Sentiment = 'N', 1, 0)) as Negative,
  SUM(IF(Sentiment = 'Y', 1, 0)) as Positive,
  SUM(IF(Sentiment = 'N', 1, 0)) as Neutral
  COUNT(*) as Total
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY
  Name
```

To use t-SQL, or to just use CASE WHEN's, that same code could look like:

```
SELECT
  Name as CandidateName,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sentiment = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Negative,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sentiment = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Positive,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Sentiment = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Neutral
  COUNT(*) as Total
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY
  Name
```

Comment: In MySQL, as per the tag, this can be   `SUM(Sentiment = 'N') as Negative`